# Groovy: assertion failed for Map<String, Object>?

Tags: groovy, assert

Disclaimer: I'm new to Groovy.

I'm aware of this:

```java
String foo = "foo"
assert foo == "foo"     // true
assert "$foo" == "foo"  // true
```

But now I'm working on the code below:

```java
String a="a"
Map<String, Object> c = ["$a": [b: 'b']] // [a:[b:b]]
assert c == ["$a":[b:'b']] // true
assert c == ["a":[b:'b']]  // false

Caught: Assertion failed: 

assert c == ["a":[b:'b']]
       | |
       | false
       [a:['b':'b']]

Assertion failed: 

assert c == ["a":[b:'b']]
       | |
       | false
       [a:['b':'b']]

    at 1.run(1.groovy:4)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

I'm lost. Why is the second assertion false?

Comment: can you show the complete assert failure with stack trace

Comment: sure, done. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maps don't use equality for their key set but they use the hash code.
So while the *result* in your output *looks* the same (e.g. `.toString()`
is used) and *looks* like it *should* work, it actually can not.

```
def x = "x"
assert x=="$x" // works due to equals
assert x.hashCode() == "$x".hashCode()
// fails:
// Caught: Assertion failed: 
// 
// assert x.hashCode() == "$x".hashCode()
//        | |          |    |  |
//        | 120        false|  157
//        'x'               'x'
```

So you have to use the rather verbose `[("$a".toString()): ...]` here
(which assumes, that you are not actually just using the value `a` here
(which would be easier written as `[(a): ...]`) and rather something
more complex).

Rule of thumb: always use immutable data as keys for your maps.

Answer (score 0):

cfrick's answer has the correct workaround, but the root cause is that I was unwittingly comparing a GString to String:

```java
// String
def a="a" // notice def, to let the compiler decide. NOTE: GString a="a" will fail since Groovy won't cast it
assert a.getClass() == java.lang.String // because that's the default when there are no variables

// GString
def b="$a" // quoted variables create GStrings, not Strings. Here, you could also write Gstring b="$a"
assert b.getClass() == org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl // because of the interpolation
assert "$b".toString().getClass() == java.lang.String          // because you converted it

// String
String c="$a"
assert c.getClass() == java.lang.String // because you set the data type to String

// String
def d=(a) // not a, but (a), an expression
assert d.getClass() == java.lang.String // because a is String
assert d.getClass() != org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl

// String
String e="${ -> a }" // with zero arguments, the entire closure result is returned
assert e.getClass() == java.lang.String // lazy evaluation - because you set the data type to String

// Map (verbose)
Map<String, Object> f = [("$b".toString()): [c: 'c']] // to use a var as a key, you need an expression, thus ()
assert f == [("$b".toString()): [c: 'c']] // because you force b from GString to String
assert f != [("$b"): [c: 'c']] // because b is Gstring, not String

// Map (less verbose)
Map<String, Object> g = [ (b.toString()): [c: 'c']] // to use a var as a key, you need an expression, thus ()
assert g == [ (b.toString()): [c: 'c']] // because you force b from GString to String
assert g != [("$b"): [c: 'c']] // because b is Gstring, not String
```

Answer (score 0):

My personal iron rule:

- Never use GStrings as keys if you instantiate the Map directly using `[:]` notation and
- never use GStrings as keys to add or get values from a Map using Java methods `[:].put()` or `[:].get()`.

In these cases, the type of your keys will be GStrings and as already pointed out, this is bad. Here is another funky behaviour:

```
String a = "key-1"
Map map = ["$a": 1]      // key is GString
assert map."$a" == null  // looks for String and does not find it
assert map["$a"] == null // looks for String and does not find it
```

You will not be able to find the very key you have just put into the Map using dot or getAt notation. The reason is that the way `hashCode()` was implemented for GString

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 37 + toString().hashCode();
}
```

Without the 37 it would have been fine...
But sometimes it is very handy to use GStrings to access Maps like so

```
String a = "key-1"
Map map = ["key-1": 1]
assert map."$a" == 1
assert map["$a"] == 1

String b = "key-2"
map."$b" = 2
assert map.get(b) == 2
```

and that is fine, because with dot or getAt notation Groovy treats GStrings as Strings for some reason, so we don't violate @cfrick's rule

> always use immutable data as keys for your maps.